# How can I pull in my own module (package of functions) from GitHub into a Jupyter notebook or .py file?

Tags: python, git, github, package

I have a **personal** module saved on my Windows machine with a bunch of functions I tend to use often. I usually just import it by using `from ___ import *` and keep the module saved in `Google Drive` desktop so it automatically syncs across my desktop.

I want to start using GitHub more often, and figured uploading my module there into a repo and then pulling it via URL would be neat (and I could more easily share with people). Problem is, I'm new to Git and as far as I can tell, this isn't exactly.. that common of a use case?

I'm imaging something as simple as importing data from a url and loading it as a module, but not sure how to do this. Thanks!